# $SO(1, 1)$ and $Spin(1, 1)$ in terms of $GL(1, R)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, semi-riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry

We know that

$\mathsf{Spin}(2)$ is a double cover of $\mathsf{SO}(2)$, which means it is a double cover of $\mathsf{U}(1)$. So both $\mathsf{Spin}(2)$ and $\mathsf{SO}(2)$ are $\mathsf{U}(1)$.  They are isomorphic $\mathsf{Spin}(2) \cong \mathsf{SO}(2)$. The double cover of $\mathsf{U}(1)$ is still a $\mathsf{U}(1)$.

Now, how do we show that $\mathsf{SO}(1, 1) = \mathsf{GL}(1, \Bbb R)$? and $\mathsf{Spin}(1, 1) = \mathsf{GL}(1, \Bbb R)$? Are they isomorphic $\mathsf{SO}(1, 1) \cong \mathsf{Spin}(1, 1)$?

p.s. $\mathsf{GL}(1,\Bbb R)$ is simply the real number $\mathsf{GL}(1,\Bbb R)=\Bbb R−0$ excluding the zero.  What I am confused is that if I use $(x,y)=(\cosh(u),\sinh(u))$ to label the coordinates on $\mathsf{SO}(1, 1)$ or $\mathsf{Spin}(1, 1)$ where it is parametrized by $x^2−y^2=$ constant, I do not see a particular reason why we need to exclude the zero origin. I mean the $u\in \Bbb R$ spans the full real part. The $u=0$ is allowed!

Comment: Can you find an explicit parameterization for $SO(1,1)$?

Comment: First, (1,) is simply the real number $(1,)=R - {0}$ excluding the zero. Agree?

Comment: $(1,1)$ is parametrized by $x^2-y^2=$ constant. So we can label $x$ and $y$ by cosh and sinh hyperbolic cosine / sine functions.

Comment: So $(x,y)= (cosh(u), sinh(u))$, which $u \in $ in real number. But here it seems $u$ can also be at the origin. I do not need to exclude the origin. Is there a reason to get (1,)=−0 excluding the zero?

Comment: You're correct that $GL(1,\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^*$, i.e. the nonzero reals with multiplication. Your description of $SO(1,1)$ makes less sense (though you're on the right track with hyperbolic functions): the elements should be $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Could you write an answer? I am confused why excluding the origin? please

Comment: $GL(1,\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the set of *invertible* linear transformations $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, each of which corresponds to a real number. 0 is not invertible.

Comment: Yes, as I said "(1,) is simply the real number (1,)=−0 excluding the zero." What I am confused is that if I use (,)=(ℎ(),ℎ()) to label the coordinates on (1,1) or (1,1), I do not see a particular reason why we need to exclude the zero origin. I mean the $u \in R$ spans the full real part!!! thanks

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by the expression $(x,y)=(\cosh(u),\sinh(u))$, or how it as anything to do with $SO(1,1)$ or $Spin(1,1)$. $SO(1,1)$ should be a (parameterized) set of 2x2 matrices, and $Spin(1,1)$ should be a (parameterized) subset of the Clifford algebra $Cl(\mathbb{R}^{1,1})$

Comment: matrix} Yes, I got a rank-2 matrix $M$ satisfies $$M^T \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} M =T \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: such that the $$M = \begin{pmatrix}cosh(u) & sinh(u) \\ sinh(u) &cosh(u)  \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: but I do not see why the $M = \begin{pmatrix}cosh(u) & sinh(u) \\ sinh(u) &cosh(u)  \end{pmatrix} $ needs to be parametrized by ℝ -0. I meant that $u \in ℝ$? the full range of ℝ? not  ℝ -0.

Comment: That parameterization doesn't cover all of $SO(1,1)$, however, if you add the negatives you get a map $f:\mathbb{R}\times\{\pm 1\}\to SO(1,1)$ given by$$f(u,b)=b\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(u)&\sinh(u)\\\sinh(u)&\cosh(u)\end{pmatrix}$$This gives a group isomorphism. Can you find similar group isomorphisms $\mathbb{R}\times\{\pm 1\}\to GL(1,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathbb{R}\times\{\pm 1\}\to Spin(1,1)$?

Comment: Sorry I am slightly confused, do we mean to have
$$
(1,ℝ)   \cong ℝ×{±1}
$$ or $$
(1,ℝ)   \cong (ℝ-0) ×{±1}
$$
or $$
(1,ℝ)   \cong (ℝ-0) ?
$$

Comment: The first. By $\mathbb{R}$ I mean the group of real numbers with addition as the group operation, whereas $GL(1,\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^*$ is the group of nonzero real numbers with multiplication as the group operation.